# Python - UnboundLocalError: local variable 'randomemails1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

**Hello guys, so i've been getting this code on my Python code. I would love to solve the error. Thanks.**
*Code:*

```
    for users in usernames:
    try:
        k = 1
        filename = './Modules/randomemails.txt'
        with open(filename) as file:
            randomemails = reservoir_sample(file, k) # get k random lines
            randomemails1 = randomemails
        if not randomemails: # file is empty
            sys.exit() # do nothing, exit immediately
        delete_lines(filename, randomemails) # delete them from the file
    except:
        pass
    
    print(str(randomemails1))
```

I get the following error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'randomemails1' referenced before assignment

**What are the possible solutions?**

Answer (score 1):

Si ocurre un error, la excepción funcionará y la variable no se inicializa, debe establecer su valor desde el principio

```
for users in usernames:
    randomemails1 = ""
    try:
        k = 1
        filename = './Modules/randomemails.txt'
        with open(filename) as file:
            randomemails = reservoir_sample(file, k) # get k random lines
            randomemails1 = randomemails
        if not randomemails: # file is empty
            sys.exit() # do nothing, exit immediately
        delete_lines(filename, randomemails) # delete them from the file
    except:
        pass
    
    print(str(randomemails1))
```

Comment: Hola Danis! Eres nuevo y probablemente no lo sepas, pero para no llenar el sitio de preguntas en distintos idiomas, solo esta bien visto contestar las preguntas en Español :)

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Lo siento, no prestes atención al hecho de que la pregunta está escrita en inglés. No soy un principiante, tengo más de 5 mil reputación en la versión rusa

Comment: Tranquilo @Danis , soy español jaja